# Generating multiple data with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables as below

**Product_Asset:**

```
PAId      Tracks
1          2
2          3
```

**Product_Asset_Resource:**

```
Id        PAId        TrackNumber
1          1              1 
2          1              2 
3          2              1
4          2              2 
5          2              3
```

I would like to know if I can generate the data in `product_asset_resource` table based on `product_asset` table using TSQL query (without complex cursor etc.)

For example, if the number of tracks in `product_asset`  is 3 then I need to populate 3 rows in `product_asset_resource` with track numbers as 1,2,3

Comment: You'll need to have a numbers table (or use a virtual tally table). Just join that with number <= tracks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the help of a [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

```
WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(Tracks) FROM Product_Asset) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT
    Id  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pa.PAId, t.N),
    pa.PAId,
    TrackNumber = t.N
FROM Product_Asset pa
INNER JOIN CteTally t
    ON t.N <= pa.Tracks
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/479224)</kbd>

Comment: Taught me something I didn't know +1.

Comment: @rontornambe glad I could help. You could do a lot with Tally Table. I suggest you read the referenced article.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I am not using any **Tally Table**

```
declare @Product_Asset table(PAId int,Tracks int)
insert into @Product_Asset values (1 ,2),(2, 3)

;with CTE as
(
select PAId,1 TrackNumber from @Product_Asset
union all

select  pa.PAId,TrackNumber+1 from @Product_Asset pa
inner join cte c on pa.PAId=c.PAId
where c.TrackNumber<pa.Tracks
)

select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by paid)id, * from cte
```

IMHO,Recursive CTE or sub query or using temp table performance depend upon example to example.

I find Recursive CTE more  readable and won't use them unless they exhibit performance problem.

I am not convince that Recursive CTE is hidden RBAR.
CTE is just syntax so in theory it is just a subquery

We can take any example to prove that using #Temp table will improve the performance ,that doesn't mean we always use temp table.

Similarly in this example using Tally Table may not improve the performance this do not imply that we should take help of Tally Table at all.

Comment: Recursive CTEs do not scale very well on large data. Please read [**this**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/) excellent article by Jeff Moden.